# Title:Updating the current cells valued retrieved using user form vba

Tags: vba, excel

A friend of mine needed some help so here it goes :

I have a **search Button** in my user form, however when I want to **update** the values that I have retrieved, I can't seem to update it.

It shows some error message, when I have tried to run the **update button** :

> `Run-time Error "1004"`

This is my **search button** command code:

```
Private Sub CommandSearchButton2_Click()
Dim lastrow
Dim ProjCode As String
Dim LabelProjName As String
Dim LabelSummary As String
Dim LabelAccount1 As String
Dim LabelAccount2 As String
Dim LabelProjManager As String
Dim LabelCountry As String
Dim LabelRegulatory As String
Dim LabelRiskLvl As String
Dim LabelSchForecast As String
Dim LabelSchPar As String
Dim LabelImpact As String
Dim LabelCustNonRetail As String
Dim LabelCustRetail As String
Dim LabOutsourcingImp As String
Dim LabelListImpacted As String


    searchRow = 0
    lastrow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    ProjCode = TextBoxProjCode.Text

 For currentrow = 33 To 8000

    If Cells(currentrow, 10).Text = ProjCode Then

        searchRow = currentrow

        TextBoxProjCode.Text = Cells(currentrow, 10).Text
        TextBoxProjName.Text = Cells(currentrow, 5)
        TextBoxSummary.Text = Cells(currentrow, 6)
        TextBoxAcc1.Text = Cells(currentrow, 7)
        TextBoxAcc2.Text = Cells(currentrow, 8)
        TextBoxProjM.Text = Cells(currentrow, 9)
        TextBoxCountry.Text = Cells(currentrow, 11)
        TextBoxRegulatory.Text = Cells(currentrow, 12)
        TextBoxRiskLvl.Text = Cells(currentrow, 13)
        TextBoxSchForecast.Text = Cells(currentrow, 16)
        TextBoxSchPar.Text = Cells(currentrow, 18)
        TextBoxImpact.Text = Cells(currentrow, 19)
        TextBoxCustNonRetail.Text = Cells(currentrow, 20)
        TextBoxCustRetail.Text = Cells(currentrow, 21)
        TextBoxOutsourcingImp.Text = Cells(currentrow, 22)
        TextBoxListImpt.Text = Cells(currentrow, 23)

    End If

Next currentrow

TextBoxProjCode.SetFocus
End Sub
```

the search command button seems to work as i am able to retrieve the values from the selected cells.

this is my **update button**command  code:

```
Private Sub CommandUpdateButton_Click()
Dim lastrow
Dim ProjCode As String
Dim LabelProjName As String
Dim LabelSummary As String
Dim LabelAccount1 As String
Dim LabelAccount2 As String
Dim LabelProjManager As String
Dim LabelCountry As String
Dim LabelRegulatory As String
Dim LabelRiskLvl As String
Dim LabelSchForecast As String
Dim LabelSchPar As String
Dim LabelImpact As String
Dim LabelCustNonRetail As String
Dim LabelCustRetail As String
Dim LabOutsourcingImp As String
Dim LabelListImpacted As String

    ProjCode = TextBoxProjCode.Text
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(searchRow, 10).Value = ProjCode

    LabelProjName = TextBoxProjName.Text
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(searchRow, 5).Value = LabelProjName

    LabelSummary = TextBoxSummary.Text
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(searchRow, 6).Value = LabelSummary

    LabelAccount1 = TextBoxAcc1.Text
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(searchRow, 7).Value = LabelAccount1

    LabelAccount2 = TextBoxAcc2.Text
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(searchRow, 8).Value = LabelAccount2

    LabelProjManager = TextBoxProjM.Text
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(searchRow, 9).Value = LabelProjManager

    LabelCountry = TextBoxCountry.Text
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(searchRow, 11).Value = LabelCountry

    LabelRegulatory = TextBoxRegulatory.Text
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(searchRow, 12).Value = LabelRegulatory

    LabelRiskLvl = TextBoxRiskLvl.Text
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(searchRow, 13).Value = LabelRiskLvl

    LabelSchForecast = TextBoxSchForecast.Text
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(searchRow, 16).Value = LabelSchForecast

    LabelSchPar = TextBoxSchPar.Text
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(searchRow, 18).Value = LabelSchPar

    LabelImpact = TextBoxImpact.Text
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(searchRow, 19).Value = LabelImpact

    LabelCustNonRetail = TextBoxCustNonRetail.Text
     Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(searchRow, 20).Value = LabelCustNonRetail





End Sub
```

I hope anyone could help me in this cos I am not so good in VBA coding. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare your variable `SearchRow` as `Public` by declaring it at the top of the module, before any other code (sub, function, ...) , with :

```
Public SearchRow As Long
```

Here is your amended code :

```
Private Sub CommandSearchButton2_Click()
Dim LastRow As Long, _
    CurrentRow As Long, _
    ProjCode As String

    SearchRow = 0
    LastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    ProjCode = TextBoxProjCode.Text

For CurrentRow = 33 To 8000
    If Cells(CurrentRow, 10).Text = ProjCode Then
        SearchRow = CurrentRow

        TextBoxProjCode.Text = Cells(CurrentRow, 10).Text
        TextBoxProjName.Text = Cells(CurrentRow, 5)
        TextBoxSummary.Text = Cells(CurrentRow, 6)
        TextBoxAcc1.Text = Cells(CurrentRow, 7)
        TextBoxAcc2.Text = Cells(CurrentRow, 8)
        TextBoxProjM.Text = Cells(CurrentRow, 9)
        TextBoxCountry.Text = Cells(CurrentRow, 11)
        TextBoxRegulatory.Text = Cells(CurrentRow, 12)
        TextBoxRiskLvl.Text = Cells(CurrentRow, 13)
        TextBoxSchForecast.Text = Cells(CurrentRow, 16)
        TextBoxSchPar.Text = Cells(CurrentRow, 18)
        TextBoxImpact.Text = Cells(CurrentRow, 19)
        TextBoxCustNonRetail.Text = Cells(CurrentRow, 20)
        TextBoxCustRetail.Text = Cells(CurrentRow, 21)
        TextBoxOutsourcingImp.Text = Cells(CurrentRow, 22)
        TextBoxListImpt.Text = Cells(CurrentRow, 23)

        Exit For
    End If
Next CurrentRow

TextBoxProjCode.SetFocus
End Sub


Private Sub CommandUpdateButton_Click()
Dim LastRow As Long, _
    CurrentRow As Long, _
    ProjCode As String, _
    Ws As Worksheet
Dim LabelProjName As String
Dim LabelSummary As String
Dim LabelAccount1 As String
Dim LabelAccount2 As String
Dim LabelProjManager As String
Dim LabelCountry As String
Dim LabelRegulatory As String
Dim LabelRiskLvl As String
Dim LabelSchForecast As String
Dim LabelSchPar As String
Dim LabelImpact As String
Dim LabelCustNonRetail As String
Dim LabelCustRetail As String
Dim LabOutsourcingImp As String
Dim LabelListImpacted As String

Set Ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    ProjCode = TextBoxProjCode.Text
    Ws.Cells(SearchRow, 10).Value = ProjCode

    LabelProjName = TextBoxProjName.Text
    Ws.Cells(SearchRow, 5).Value = LabelProjName

    LabelSummary = TextBoxSummary.Text
    Ws.Cells(SearchRow, 6).Value = LabelSummary

    LabelAccount1 = TextBoxAcc1.Text
    Ws.Cells(SearchRow, 7).Value = LabelAccount1

    LabelAccount2 = TextBoxAcc2.Text
    Ws.Cells(SearchRow, 8).Value = LabelAccount2

    LabelProjManager = TextBoxProjM.Text
    Ws.Cells(SearchRow, 9).Value = LabelProjManager

    LabelCountry = TextBoxCountry.Text
    Ws.Cells(SearchRow, 11).Value = LabelCountry

    LabelRegulatory = TextBoxRegulatory.Text
    Ws.Cells(SearchRow, 12).Value = LabelRegulatory

    LabelRiskLvl = TextBoxRiskLvl.Text
    Ws.Cells(SearchRow, 13).Value = LabelRiskLvl

    LabelSchForecast = TextBoxSchForecast.Text
    Ws.Cells(SearchRow, 16).Value = LabelSchForecast

    LabelSchPar = TextBoxSchPar.Text
    Ws.Cells(SearchRow, 18).Value = LabelSchPar

    LabelImpact = TextBoxImpact.Text
    Ws.Cells(SearchRow, 19).Value = LabelImpact

    LabelCustNonRetail = TextBoxCustNonRetail.Text
    Ws.Cells(SearchRow, 20).Value = LabelCustNonRetail

Set Ws = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Thx for accepting my answer! :)
And don't forget to up/down vote the post that you find useful/useless! ;)
(an upvote on the useful answers of your question is fairly welcome too)

Answer (score 0):

In your Update button code, you doesnt have value for variable searchRow, cause this searchRow variable got value in SearchButton sub not Updatebutton Sub.

You can store searchRow and send it as parameter in Update button code.

Comment: Sorry but how do you send it as parameter? any suggested code? @dtk142